# ADO Error Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, dao

I have used the ADO function `CheckInvTotals` in an Access 2010 database for 5 years without a problem. Recently I have migrated to Office 2019 and this function failed returning the following message:

> Error -2147024882 (Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation.)

I can test this function bypassing startup forms. Executing the function in this manner still fails with error above, so it is unlikely that other running objects are causing memory leaks.

I reference `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library`.
I would like to know why ADO fails and receive suggestions as to what I might try to eliminate the error in the ADO routine.

1. I have tried referencing an earlier version of ADO to no avail
2. The enclosed DAO code `CheckInvTotals2` functions without error
3. The ADO failure also occurs in Office 2016

```vb
Public Function CheckInvTotals(lngPayID As Long) As Boolean
    'Is there a difference between Invoice Total and payment amount

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    On Error GoTo CheckInvTotals_Error

    With cmd
        .CommandText = "qryprmInvDiff"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        Set .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("PayID", adBigInt, adParamInput, , lngPayID)
        rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
        Set rst = .Execute
    End With

    CheckInvTotals = rst.EOF
    rst.Close

CheckInvTotals_Error:
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")"
    End If

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
End Function

Public Function CheckInvTotals2(lngPayID As Long) As Boolean
    'Is there a difference between Invoice Total and payment amount

    Dim db As Database
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim prmPayID As DAO.Parameter
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    On Error GoTo Handle_err

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qd = db.QueryDefs("qryprmInvDiff")
    Set prmPayID = qd.Parameters!PayID
    prmPayID.Value = lngPayID

    Set rst = qd.OpenRecordset
    CheckInvTotals2 = rst.EOF
    rst.Close

Handle_err:
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Format(Err.Number) & " " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set prmPayID = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

SQL `qryprmInvDiff`:

```
PARAMETERS PayID Long;
SELECT Creditors.CName, Creditors.Code, [InvTotal]-[Amount] AS Diff FROM 
Creditors INNER JOIN (Payments INNER JOIN qryPayInvTotal ON 
Payments.ID = qryPayInvTotal.PayID) ON Creditors.ID = Payments.CID
WHERE ((([InvTotal]-[Amount])<>0) AND ((Payments.PID)=[PayID]));
```

The code should simply return `true` or `false`.

Comment: You are retrieving a Recordset purely to see whether there are any records.  You should write a SQL command which will return the count of records which will indicate zero or not zero which will be far more efficient.  You should also specify `adForwardOnly` unless you specifically need to move backwards through the records (which you don't in your example).  Every query should bring back the smallest amount of data you need.  It's faster and more efficient.

Comment: Have you considered whether the problem could be due to the use of a 64-bit Microsoft Access?

Comment: Thanks @Gareth. Agreed, it is my poor form  to simply test EOF state rather than return a record count. However modifying the query to sum records returned fails with the error ...Expression too complex to be evaluated. I think that's why I opted for the EOF test. I have modified the cursor to use adOpenForwardOnly without success

Comment: Thanks @UnhandledException Indeed further reading suggests that ADO.Net may solve the problem but that is not an option within Access using VBA. Years ago I believed that DAO was going to be replaced by ADO so I tried to use ADO whenever possible. Now it seems that DAO is preferred by MS within the Office/VBA environment

Answer (score 1):

a little bit too late, but today I had this issue and perhaps some other guys too...

MS Infos: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/adbigint-data-type-errors

Solution: change adBigInt to more appropriate value, in my case adNumeric does the job

````
  Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command

  RS.MoveFirst

  With Cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = strSQL

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@idposition", adChar, adParamInput, 36, strGUID)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@idbeleg", adChar, adParamInput, 36, RS.Fields("idbeleg"))

    ' ########### A2019 > adBigInt changed to adNumeric (Database Datatype: Long (Integer))
    '.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@sortnr", adBigInt, adParamInput, , RS.Fields("sortnr"))

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@sortnr", adNumeric, adParamInput, , RS.Fields("sortnr"))
```
````